# Что делают с участником, написавшим в ответ явный спам?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, блокировка

Недавно  встретился явный спам (поскольку удален, не помню, кто писал, и чего точно). Чего-то типа:

> Слава славику, слава Украине, слава России и слава дурочку.

Мне интересно: что модераторы делают с такими участниками? На первый раз прощают, иль же банят?

Comment: Помимо наказания от модераторов, [снимают 100 репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) (если сообщение получает 6 тревог за спам)

Comment: Это разве спам? Что это сообщение рекламирует? Славика и Украину?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зависит от тяжести. Если человек просто наспамил или написал чушь, то обычно удаляем и пишем в личку, чтоб соблюдал правила. Если после этого продолжит, то, вероятно, будет бан.

Если в сообщении явные оскорбления и мат, то сразу будет бан скорей всего.

Всё зависит от ситуации, но бан - это всегда крайняя мера.

Comment: @Sevastopol' если человек просто грубит, то на первый раз можно сделать предупреждение. В данном случае, думаю, это бы не помогло. В целом баны у нас редко происходят. Бывает, что создают новорегов просто для спама, такие просто удаляются.