# На каком основании был удален вопрос о соответствии текста лицензии LGPL?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, удаление-вопросов

[Данный вопрос совместимости текста лицензии с LGPL был удален](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1386303).

Хотелось бы поинтересоваться причинами, так как вопрос имел отличный ответ и был по тематике Ru.SO.

Comment: Вы текст читали вопроса? Там до тематики so как до луны.

Comment: @tym32167 вы можете ответить на вопрос, нажав кнопку "Ответить".

Comment: @tym32167 да, если вы считаете, что это является причиной и вы считаете это ответом на мой вопрос. Также, вы можете предложить закрыть мой вопрос подходящим дубликатом. Во время моего поиска, я не нашел подходящего по моему мнению.

Comment: Вопрос справедливый, если вы новичок на сайте. От вас я такого вопроса не ждал - видимо вы что то высказать хотели, да не высказали, вот я и отписался в комментах. Но раз просите - написал ответом.

Comment: @tym32167 вопросы пишут по разным причинам. В том числе для того, чтобы ответ на него был на сайте (для этого можно ответить на него самому, например). Или по другим причинам.

Comment: Пишите на здоровье, кто ж против. Я пояснил что и как сделал и выполнил вашу просьбу - написал ответ.

Answer (score 11):

для политики здесь есть отдельный чатик.

кроме того, обсуждаемый вопрос содержал мат. по поводу мата (выделено мной):

- > [Нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct)
  > Неприемлемое поведение
  > Никакого преследования. В том числе, но не ограничиваясь: травля, шантаж, **нецензурная лексика**, прямые и завуалированные угрозы, высказывания сексуального характера, неприличное и бестактное поведение, а также постоянное неконструктивное встревание в дискуссии.
- [Допустимо ли использование мата в никнеймах пользователей?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/212/178576)
- [Что делают с участником, написавшим в ответ явный спам?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10421/178576)

p.s. я пытался спасти вопрос, убрав из него политику и мат, но правка была отменена другим участником. войну, даже в виде правок, я, конечно, не приветствую.

Comment: Спасибо, пока читал нормы поведения, абсолютно случайно не нашел пункта о нецензурной лексике. Но существуют еще и другие способы: обратный откат, блокировка содержимого, закрытие комментариев.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, а [первоисточник на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) вы разве не читали? ну, и, кстати, если вам не видна причина удаления, то вот она: «Это сообщение скрыто. Оно было отмечено как спам или оскорбительный материал и удалено 2 часа назад участниками Дух сообщества Бот.» // вероятно, кто-то отметил его тревогой как спам или оскорбление.

Comment: Нет, так как у меня только 839 репутации, мне показываются только "удалено в процессе модерации". На английском конечно читал, на английском я его наизусть знаю. А вот на русском увы нет, не являюсь модератором Ру.СО и читал только раз 5, кроме того, нецензураная лексика в вопросах - это нормально на [Русский Язык SE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), при наличии соответствующих меток и некоторым другим условиям.

Comment: Понимаю. этот ответ и комментарии под ним раскрывают тему очень хорошо.

Answer (score 9):

Потому что политическим вбросам не место на нашем сайте.